# Can I block some dates in the django calender datepicker

Tags: python, django, filter, datetimepicker

I am trying to design a self-scheduling meeting page using Django. I am planning to use DateTime picker and show the available time slots to book. In datepicker how can I block the unavailable time slots? I have check DateFromToRangeFilter filter etc. Seems like these functionalities cannot satisfy my requirement. Can someone guide me how to block few dates in Django DateTime picker? Also, please find that I get the available slot's data from A third party in a form of excel and I don't have it in my Django database. Thanks in advance.